# CakePHP controller action setting cookie and passing to helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, http-post

I checked [typical CakePHP request](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/a-typical-cakephp-request.html) but couldn't find the solution.

At first `myThemeCookie` doesn't exist. By setting this cookie, user can select his/her favorite theme and he/she will see that theme in the future.

I have `myController` and `myAction`. I have a form in `myAction.ctp`. User can select theme name.

At first request `myAction` checks for `$_POST`. It can't find any value. Action only shows form.

In second request, when user submits form, I send user to `myAction` again. Action finds `$_POST` data. Getting theme css address from `$_POST`. By using `myComponent`, `myThemeCookie` is written.

Then I have `myLayout.ctp` file. This layout file uses `myHelper` and by using `myHelper->getCookieTheme()`, it gets theme name from the cookie. But helper gives empty name. So user sees old theme's fonts. (Note that I check cookie data by using `$_COOKIE` variable in helper)

When I refresh myAction page and make a third request I see that  `myHelper->getCookieTheme()` gives right css file name. And user sees new theme's fonts.

So, after I set a cookie in myAction, I can't see it in my helper method and layout file. But it seems like view/helper files are calculated after controller actions. Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do that in the view at all. Also don't access $_POST directly but use the request object $this->request in the controller.

have a method like checkThemeFromCookie() in your AppController and call it in beforeRender() and read the theme from the cookie, if the value is not empty simply do $this->theme = $themeFromCookie. If the cookie is empty just leave the property or set whatever default theme you want.

References

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

Comment: I use a CDN for theme files. So I pass a HTML to my layout/helper. Is it OK to set $this->theme. And access it inside layout/helper ?

Comment: I will create new variable with ```public $theme="mytheme"``` inside my derived controller and set it from the AppController ? I couldn't understand where to set ```$this->theme``` ?

Comment: It's not a variable it's a property. If you set in your controller derived from AppController you'll override what you set in AppController. OOP basics. Since you want to (I guess so) have the theme applied everywhere you will have to do the cookie check and setting the theme in the AppController. If not put the check in the AppController and the set in the controllers that need it.

Comment: CDN theme files? Define what a theme for you is. Did you read the links I've provided? I think we talk about two different things. Assets vs theme views.

Comment: I include "my_theme.css" file inside my layout file. Regarding to user's selection the file name changes. File exists in CDN and regarding to cookie I set a URL and include it inside my layout.ctp file.

Comment: That must not be ```$this->theme```. Any other property that can be reachable from controller and also from views/helpers is ok. I can set it from controller/component. I will reach that from my view/helper. I prefer a global property, rather then passing variable from controller to view by using ```set``` command.